# Excel 2007 Duplicate Check Wrongly Converting Hex as Exponent

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, hex

I have a spreadsheet used to verify a long list of 8-digit hexadecimal numbers for duplicates.

It has two columns - one for the hexadecimal values and another where the following formula is used to check for duplicates (given that this second column is column B):

=COUNTIF($B:$B, B1)

This has worked fine for most numbers except for these values:

69000700 and 690007E2.

The first column is formatted as text, however it seems that the COUNTIF function is doing some kind of unwanted implicit cast of my hex value, and taking the second hex value as an exponent (which would make it the same as the first value).

It also doesn't seem to matter what format my hex column is - the COUNTIF function always interprets these values as numbers and therefore they appear as duplicates.

Is there a way to ensure the COUNTIF function takes these cell values as string parameters without doing an implicit cast?

Comment: Once converted it stays converted. You should format as text *before* putting the value into the cell. I think that in this way you could avoid the helper column..

Comment: This is a problem specific to COUNTIF (or the family of "IF" functions like SUMIF, COUNTIF, AVERAGEIF etc.), it always treats any text value that could be interpreted as a number as that number, e.g. values like 1/1 might be interpreted as dates - using SUMPRODUCT would fix this without changing your data, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$1000=B1)+0)` - that's less efficient (slower) hence the reduced range.....or as you don't really need a count use MATCH like `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,$B:$B,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's feasible to add an extra column with a formula

```
=CHAR(34) & B1 & CHAR(34)
```

copied down.

The formula encloses the text into quotes, and `"690007E2"` will no longer be interpreted as `"69000700"` (Excel 2003).

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I had to edit my COUNTIF function to add an IF statement so it is now =IF(B1<>"", COUNTIF($B:$B, B1), 0). This edit was required because with the quotes added, the COUNTIF function was seeing all empty cells as duplicates.